# From where can i download Neo4j Community Edition 3.2.13?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to install Neo4j Community Edition version 3.2.13.

I checked  the Neo4j download page but I didn't find it knowing that Neo4j might not offer older versions like 3.2.13 on their main download page.

Is there a way to download this specific version or are there any alternative repositories where I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it using the tarball links :

```
wget http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-3.2.13-unix.tar.gz
```

or for Windows

```
wget http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-3.2.13-windows.zip
```

Comment: i apreciate thank you! but i'm using windows as OS

Comment: @chaimachaima added the link for windows as well

Comment: + docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.2/installation/

Answer (score 0):

A handy feature of Google Chrome that helps you in those cases are [quoted searches](https://blog.google/products/search/how-were-improving-search-results-when-you-use-quotes/).

> Put quotes around any word or phrase, such as [“wireless phone chargers”], and we’ll only show pages that contain those exact words or phrases.

By searching [neo4j Community Edition "3.2.13"](https://www.google.com/search?q=neo4j%20Community%20Edition%20%223.2.13%22) you'll find various places to download from:

- [the largest **Windows** package repository & manager Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/neo4j-community/3.2.13)

  - `choco install neo4j-community --version=3.2.13`
- some more, one of which led me to the [Neo4j Deployment Center](https://neo4j.com/deployment-center/) page, where - as you've said - older versions can't be downloaded anymore, but right below that [Neo4j repositories are shown](https://neo4j.com/deployment-center/#repositories-gdb) for **[RHEL](https://yum.neo4j.com/) and [Debian/Ubuntu](https://debian.neo4j.com/)-based Linux** systems

  - both show in the very last section "Installing other versions" how to do as you wish (after having added the repository as described in the docs there):

    - `sudo yum install neo4j-3.2.13` for RHEL.
    - `sudo apt-get install neo4j=1:3.2.13` for Debian/Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you this was helpfull!                                                                                                                               and for neo4j repositories I checked them but unfortunately I can't use them because i'am using windows

Comment: @chaimachaima added the command to install Neo4j Community 3.2.13 on Winidows. :)